# Why is std::ctype's virtual destructor protected?

Tags: c++, virtual, protected

I was trying to write

```
std::ctype<char> c;
```

but I couldn't, because that class's is both `protected` (directly) and `virtual` (indirectly, through [`facet`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/facet)).

But I can do this just fine:

```
struct : std::ctype<char> { } c;
```

This made me wonder, what's the point of making [`std::ctype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype)'s destructor `protected`?

For example, is it trying to prevent a misuse or mistake? If so, what is that?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype/%7Ectype `An object of type std::ctype, like most facets, can only be destroyed when the last std::locale object that implements this facet goes out of scope or if a user-defined class is derived from std::ctype and implements a public destructor.`

Comment: https://wg21.link/lwg721 calls this a "regrettable consequence of the original design"